# Sharing common code between different node.js projects using webpack

Tags: node.js, webpack, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I have following lambda project structure:

root:

- node_modules
- common-lib
- services

  - service1

    - node_modules
    - src
    - package.json
    - tsconfig.json
    - webpack.config.js
    - serverless.yml
  - service2
  - service3
- package.json
- tsconfig.json

As you can see, I'm using TS, but currently it's combined with JS. For local start and deploying my lambdas, I'm using SLS. Webpack is used by the SLS.

Previously it was working okay, but now, we need to upgrade sequelize to version 6 (6.31.0).
And this way, transactions did not work anymore. After investigation, I've realized, that common code, which is main provider for different sequelize actions uses it's own "sequelize" from root's node_modules, but transaction was created by service1/node_modules/sequelize, and this way "instance of Transaction" check fails inside inner Sequelzie code.

So, my idea was to move-out all common packages from service package.json files to the root's package.json.
All TS errors fixed.

But now, I'm facing trobubles connected with webpack.
When It tries to bundle the whole project(for example service1), it shows me these warings:

> WARNING  Compiled with 1 warning                                            5:37:01 PM
>
> warning  in ../../node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/connection-manager.js
>
> Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
>
> 3 assets
> 731 modules
>
> WARNING in ../../node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/connection-manager.js 44:15-63
> Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
>
> WARNING in ../../node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/connection-manager.js 49:13-32
> Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
>
> webpack 5.88.2 compiled with 2 warnings in 13087 ms`

That's because sequelize uses mysql2 dependency inside, and even if it's possible to run the project, sequelize throws me runtime error later: **"Please install mysql2 package manually."**

I suggest, that webpack.config is wrong for my situation. And inner "require" statements did not for for root's "node_modules".

my webpack.config.js is so:

```
const path = require('path');
const slsw = require('serverless-webpack');
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');
const { RebuildServiceMapPlugin } = require('../../tools/utils/webpackPlugins');
const CleanTerminalPlugin = require('clean-terminal-webpack-plugin');
const FriendlyErrorsWebpackPlugin = require('@soda/friendly-errors-webpack-plugin');
const CaseSensitivePathsPlugin = require('case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = (async () => {
    return {
        
        entry: {
            'src/models': './src/models/index.js',
            'src/schema': './src/schema/index.js',
            ...slsw.lib.entries,
        },
        externals: [nodeExternals()],
        externalsPresets: { node: true },
        stats: 'minimal',
        mode: slsw.lib.webpack.isLocal ? 'development' : 'production',
        optimization: {
            minimize: false,
        },
        performance: {
            hints: false,
        },
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.js$/,
                    exclude: [/node_modules/, /..\/..\/node_modules/],
                    use: {
                        loader: 'babel-loader',
                        options: {
                            cacheDirectory: true,
                            plugins: ['source-map-support'],
                            sourceMaps: 'both',
                        },
                    },
                },
                {
                    test: /\.ts$/,
                    exclude: [/node_modules/, /..\/..\/node_modules/],
                    use: {
                        loader: 'ts-loader',
                    },
                },
                {
                    test: /\.(graphql|gql)$/,
                    exclude: [/node_modules/, /..\/..\/node_modules/],
                    loader: 'graphql-tag/loader',
                },
            ],
        },
        devtool: 'source-map',
        output: {
            path: path.join(__dirname, '.webpack'),
            filename: '[name].js',
            sourceMapFilename: '[file].map',
            libraryTarget: 'commonjs',
        },
        plugins: [
            new RebuildServiceMapPlugin({
                service: 'service1',
                stage: slsw.lib.serverless.configurationInput.provider.stage,
            }),
            new CleanTerminalPlugin(),
            new FriendlyErrorsWebpackPlugin(),
            new CaseSensitivePathsPlugin(),
        ],
        resolve: {
            extensions: ['.js', '.json', '.ts'],
            alias: {
                'common-lib': path.resolve(__dirname, '../../common-lib')
            },
            modules: [
                path.resolve(__dirname, './node_modules'),
                path.resolve(__dirname, '../../common-lib'),
                path.resolve(__dirname, '../../node_modules'),
                path.resolve(__dirname, './src'),
            ],
        },
    };
})();
```

So, what did I miss? Or may be it's even impossible to work this way with webpack? Is so, is it possible to prepare two separate webpack.config.js for root folder, bundle it separately and then somehow merge it with service1 bundle?